# how to select data from three tables using joins

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select `survey_id`, `question_id`, `question_text` and `answer_id` from the following three tables.

In SurveyTable I have:

```
Survey{survey_id,survey_title}
```

In QuestionTable I have:

```
Question{survey_id,question_id,question_text}
```

In AnswerTable:

```
Answer{question_id,answer_id,answer_text}
```

I want to select from these tables using joins. When `survey_id` is equal to the value in QuestionTable and SurveyTable.

Comment: tried anything, like  reading the manual?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to select all data from three tables using joins in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715280/how-to-select-all-data-from-three-tables-using-joins-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can start off with something like

```
SELECT  s.survey_id ,  
        q.question_id, 
        q.question_text, 
        a.answer_id,
        a.answer_text
FROM    Survey s INNER JOIN
        Question q  ON  s.survey_id = q.survey_id INNER JOIN
        Answer a    ON  q.question_id = a.question_id
```

The `INNER JOIN`s will ensure that you only have surveys where there are questions and answers available.

If you wish to return all surveys, regardless of if they have questions or answers, or even all surveys with question regardless of answers you could use `LEFT JOINS`

```
SELECT  s.survey_id ,  
        q.question_id, 
        q.question_text, 
        a.answer_id,
        a.answer_text
FROM    Survey s LEFT JOIN
        Question q  ON  s.survey_id = q.survey_id LEFT JOIN
        Answer a    ON  q.question_id = a.question_id
```

You have to try and remember that a LEFT JOUN states

Return all the data from the table on the left, and only those in the right that matches thos on the left.

Have a look at this article, it does a nice graphical explanation.

[SQL SERVER – Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

Comment: if i want that i may user where clause where s.survey_id=given by user in php at run time

Comment: in your there is not answer_text i also want answer_text

Answer (score 0):

```
select  
    survey.survey_id , 
    question.question_id,
    question.question_text,
    answer.answer_id
from survey 
left join question on question.survey_id = survey.survey_id 
left join answer on answer.question_id = question.question_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I am considering that a question can have more than one answers so I have given answer so you get all the rows of the answer table

```
 $select = "SELECT a.answer_id,a.answer_text,q.question_id, q.question_text,s.survey_id,s.survey_title FROM Answer a "
        . "LEFT JOIN Question q ON (a.question_id = q.question_id) "
        . "LEFT JOIN Survey s ON (q.survey_id = s.survey_id)";
```

Comment: i am writing this querry like this and it is giving sql syntax error select a.answer_id,answer_text,q.question_id, q.question_text,s.survey_id,s.suvrey_title from survey_answer_master 
            left join on survey_question_master q  a.question_id = q.question_id
            left join on survey_master s  q.survey_id = s.survey_id

Comment: again errro showing You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a.question_id = q.question_id
            left join survey_master on s q.survey_' at line 2

Comment: Ok thanks it worked now and i used above code also that worked also thanks